# Swift Alamofire request answer to VC with UIWebView

Tags: swift, string, request, alamofire

Im get answer from `Alamofire` request and I want to pass it in another `UIViewController` with `UIWebView`

```
{
 "result":{

    "code":"0",
    "description":""
},
 "operation":[{

    "status":boolean,
    "paymentType":integer,
    "orderID":integer",
    "paymentData":"string",
    "token":"string",
    "user":[{
    "user_status":"string",
    "userID":integer,
}]
}]
}
```

and in `paymentData` get string like this:

```
<form action="https:..." method="post">
    <input name=".." value=".." type="hidden"/>
    <input name=".." value=".." type="hidden"/>
    <input name=".." value=".." type="hidden">
    <input name=".." value="nil" type="hidden"/>
    <input name=".." value=".." type="hidden"/>
    <input name=".." value=".." type="hidden"/>
    <input name=".." value=".." type="hidden">
    <input type=".." value="PPP" style="background: #3aaf42; border: none; color: #fff; text-align: center; width: 100px; padding: 5px; margin: -15px 0 0 -50px; display: block; top: 50%; border-radius: 3px; position: absolute; left: 50%;\"/>
</form>
```

In `ViewController` with `UIWebView` where do I want to pass paymentData I have :

```
var paymentDat = ""

override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let htmlDat = paymentDat
 webView.loadHTMLString(htmlDat, baseURL: nil)
}
```

In first view im catch paymentData in Alamofire like this :

```
       Alamofire.request("http://...", method: .get, parameters: params).responseJSON { response in
        if let r = response.result.value as? NSDictionary {
            let jsss = JSON(r)

            if let result = r.value(forKey: "result") as? NSDictionary {
                if let nass = result.value(forKey: "description") as? String {
  //                        print(response.result.value)

                    if let code = result.value(forKey: "code") as? String {
         //               print(code)

                        if code == "0" {
                            if let orderIDD = jsss["operation"].array![0]["orderID"].int {
    //                                    print("order--------------------- \(orderIDD)")
                                self.webb?.orderID = orderIDD
                            }
                            if let paymentData = jsss["operation"].array![0]["paymentData"].string {
   //                                    print(paymentData)
                                self.webb?.paymentDat = paymentData

                            }
                            if paymentType == 1 {
                                self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "WebView", sender: self)
                                self.alert(title: "ОК!", message: nass)

                            } else {
                                self.alert(title: "ОК!", message: nass)

                            }
                        } else {
                            self.alert(title: "Error!", message: nass)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        } else {
            self.alert(title: "Error connect!", message: "Error connect")
        }
    }
```

How to display paymentData in another VC?

Comment: The better approach would be to pass this JSON to the URL from which yuo're getting the HTML and the URL should return the form prefilled.

Comment: @Mukesh , Requtst give me this prefilled form, and I want to transfer this form from a request to another ViewController with WebView

Comment: Your question is not clear. You have the data, you set it to the `paymentDat` variable and then you're loading the `webView` with that html string. where is the problem?

Comment: @Mukesh Yes, Im set it to the `paymentDat` and loading the `webView` but its't display in `webView`

Comment: Had you debug it and checked that you're getting the value in `paymentDat` variable in the WebView ViewController?

Comment: And also add the complete code how you're navigation to next view controller

Comment: @Mukesh Yes Im tried to print("paymentStringTest- \(paymentDat)") in `VC webView` . and in console give me `paymentStringTest- ` 
without a data

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170516/discussion-between-mukesh-and-nazar).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the value in `prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?)` method.

Add this method in your first ViewController:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

    if segue.identifier == "WebView", let webView = segue.destination as? WebViewController {
        webView.paymentDat = sender as! String
    }
}
```

Add these changes in your response code:

```
   Alamofire.request("http://...", method: .get, parameters: params).responseJSON { response in
    if let r = response.result.value as? NSDictionary {
        let jsss = JSON(r)

        if let result = r.value(forKey: "result") as? NSDictionary {
            if let nass = result.value(forKey: "description") as? String {
  //                        print(response.result.value)

                if let code = result.value(forKey: "code") as? String {
     //               print(code)

                    if code == "0" {
                        var paymentHTML = ""
                        if let orderIDD = jsss["operation"].array![0]["orderID"].int {
//                                    print("order--------------------- \(orderIDD)")
                            self.webb?.orderID = orderIDD
                        }
                        if let paymentData = jsss["operation"].array![0]["paymentData"].string {
   //                                    print(paymentData)
                            paymentHTML = paymentData

                        }
                        if paymentType == 1 {
                            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "WebView", sender: paymentHTML) // Pass 
                            self.alert(title: "ОК!", message: nass)

                        } else {
                            self.alert(title: "ОК!", message: nass)

                        }
                    } else {
                        self.alert(title: "Error!", message: nass)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    } else {
        self.alert(title: "Error connect!", message: "Error connect")
    }
}
```